# Vba sql table join on matching field where 2nd field not matching

Tags: sql, excel, vba, ms-access, select

Good day everyone.  I'm sure this is a fairly common issue but I trawled the internet and I cannot find an answer that works in my case.  I have 2 tables which both have 2 fields and both field names are the same.  I need to select all records in table 1 where the 1st field matches table 2 1st field and the 2nd field in table 2 does not match field 2 in table 1.  Sorry if I'm not explaining this very well.  Table 1 has around 10K records with client-name and country.  table 2 is a unique list of client names (around 1K) with client-name and country fields. so I need to select all the records from table 1 with same client-name but where country in table 2 is not the same as in table 1.  I've been on this for several hours now so any help would be most welcome.

The data is in 1 Access Database and I'm using ADO connection.  What I have is:-

```
 SELECT [client-name], [country] FROM [table1] LEFT JOIN [table2] ON [table1].[client-name]
 = [table2].[client-name] WHERE NOT [table1].[country] = [table2].[country];
```

Comment: Extend your join to `table1.client=table2.client and table1.country=table2.country where table2.client is null`

Comment: @Nathan_Sav Thanks so much that worked perfectly.  I didn't know you can use 'AND' to put 2 conditions into the join.  It's a great bit of knowledge to have.  Enjoy the rest of your day

Comment: no worries, i think your original would be like so "WHERE  [table1].[country] <> [table2].[country];"  Join is better though i think.